# How to add a neon hint for a 3d model of glb format on three js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, model

How to add a neon hint for a 3d model of glb format on three js
I try fix this with bloom, but it doesn't work:

```
`import Box from "@mui/joy/Box";
import {Canvas} from '@react-three/fiber';
import {useGLTF, OrbitControls, Effects} from "@react-three/drei"
import React, {Suspense} from "react";
import useScreenWidth from "../../hooks/useScreenWidth";



        <Box sx={(theme) => ({
            margin: "0 auto",
        })}>
            {
                screenWidth > 700 ? <Canvas dpr={[1, 2]} shadows camera={{fov: 45}}
                                            style={{width: "450px", height: "370px", maxWidth: "500px"}}>
                    <ambientLight/>
                    <Suspense fallback={null}>
                        {/*<directionalLight intensity={2} position={[0, 0, 10]}/>*/}
                        {/*<directionalLight intensity={2} position={[0, 0, -10]}/>*/}
                        <OrbitControls enablePan={true} enableDamping={true} enableRotate={true}                       enableZoom={false}/>
                        <Model/>
                    </Suspense>

                </Canvas> : <Canvas dpr={[1, 2]} shadows camera={{fov: 45}}
                                    style={{width: "300px", height: "300px", maxWidth: "500px"}}>
                    <ambientLight/>
                    <Suspense fallback={null}>
                        <directionalLight intensity={2} position={[0, 0, 10]}/>
                        <directionalLight intensity={2} position={[0, 0, -10]}/>
                        <OrbitControls enablePan={true} enableDamping={true} enableRotate={true}    enableZoom={false}/>

                        <Model/>
                    </Suspense>

                </Canvas>
            }


        </Box>
`
```

[as it is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VyswZ.jpg)
[as it should be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SGLpD.jpg)

I try fix this with bloom, but it doesn't work.